# How to use the input/output elements in webflow?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I'm trying to understand how the input and output elements are used in webflow. The documentation suggests that flow input/output mapping is similar to calling a method with a signature, but I don't understand what passes the flow the input value or what the flow returns output to. How do I use these elements?

I've been reading the documentation found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/defining-flows.html), but there are no examples of the elements in action that I can find. This is an example from the documentation.

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow.xsd">

<input name="hotelId" />

<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="bookingService.createBooking(hotelId, currentUser.name)"
              result="flowScope.booking" />
</on-start>

<view-state id="enterBookingDetails">
    <transition on="submit" to="reviewBooking" />
</view-state>

<view-state id="reviewBooking">
    <transition on="confirm" to="bookingConfirmed" />
    <transition on="revise" to="enterBookingDetails" />
    <transition on="cancel" to="bookingCancelled" />
</view-state>

<end-state id="bookingConfirmed" />

<end-state id="bookingCancelled" />
```

In this code, where does the value assigned to "hotelId" come from? Does the input come from the URL? If so, does `<input/>` behavior change in subflows?

Answer (score 1):

In this code, `hotelId` will be automatically mapped from the URL if you call `/myFlow?hotelId=3` (assuming your flow is called "myFlow")

but you can also set the input directly when calling the flow from another flow, i.e. using:

```
<subflow-state id="mySubflow" subflow="myFlow">
    <input name="hotelId" value="3"/>
</subflow-state>
```